# df.apply() raises IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer

Tags: python, pandas

I am performing df.apply() on a dataframe and I am getting the following error:

> IndexingError: ('Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).', 'occurred at index 4061')

This error comes from the following line of my df (at index 4061)

The relevant code is:

```py
i = pd.DataFrame()
i = df1.apply(
    lambda row: i.append(
        df.loc[
            (df1["ID"] == row["ID"])
            & (df1["Date"] >= (row["Date"] + timedelta(-5)))
            & (df1["Date"] <= (row["Date"] + timedelta(20)))
        ],
        ignore_index=True,
        inplace=True,
    )
    if row["Flag"] == 1
    else None,
    axis=1,
)
```

And an example of the first 5 rows of the df on which I am using the function:

```
 {'ID': {1: 'A US Equity',
  2: 'A US Equity',
  3: 'A US Equity',
  4: 'A US Equity',
  5: 'A US Equity'},
 'Date': {1: Timestamp('2020-12-22 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-12-23 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-12-24 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-12-28 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-12-29 00:00:00')},
 'PX_Last': {1: 117.37, 2: 117.3, 3: 117.31, 4: 117.83, 5: 117.23},
 'Short_Int': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0},
 'Total_Call_Volume': {1: 187.0, 2: 353.0, 3: 141.0, 4: 467.0, 5: 329.0},
 'Total_Put_Volume': {1: 54.0, 2: 30.0, 3: 218.0, 4: 282.0, 5: 173.0},
 'Put_OI': {1: 13354.0, 2: 13350.0, 3: 13522.0, 4: 13678.0, 5: 13785.0},
 'Call_OI': {1: 8923.0, 2: 8943.0, 3: 8973.0, 4: 9075.0, 5: 9040.0},
 'pct_chng': {1: -0.34810663949736975,
  2: -0.059640453267451043,
  3: 0.008525149190119485,
  4: 0.4432699684596253,
  5: -0.5092081812781091},
 'Short_Int_Category': {1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan},
 'Put/Call': {1: 0.2887700534759358,
  2: 0.08498583569405099,
  3: 1.5460992907801419,
  4: 0.6038543897216274,
  5: 0.5258358662613982},
 '10% + Pop Flag': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0},
 '10%-20% Pop Flag': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0},
 '20%-30% Pop Flag': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0},
 '30% + Pop Flag': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0},
 'Flag': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0},
 'Time_to_pop': {1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}}
```

The row at index 4061 that is causing the error is:

```
ID                          ADI US Equity
Date                  2021-02-24 00:00:00
PX_Last                            161.76
Short_Int                         15.1847
Total_Call_Volume                   52502
Total_Put_Volume                     1929
Put_OI                              32219
Call_OI                             45557
pct_chng                          2.57451
Short_Int_Category                  15-20
Put/Call                        0.0367415
10% + Pop Flag                          0
10%-20% Pop Flag                        0
20%-30% Pop Flag                        0
30% + Pop Flag                          0
Flag                                    1
Time_to_pop                           NaN
Name: 4061, dtype: object
```

How do I perform the function without getting the error mentioned above?

Comment: I miscopied the data, that column is included in the actual dataframe, please see my edits.

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: We're getting there. If the dict you posted is `df1`, what is `df` in your code?